# No abre una Progressive Web App (PWA) cuando estoy en modo avión

Tags: javascript, servicio, pwa

Estoy aprendiendo cómo funcionan las PWA y para ello estoy siguiendo estos [pasos](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workbox-indexeddb), pero realizando la siguiente prueba veo que no se comporta como debe.

Tengo el servidor abierto en el PC y abro la web en el navegador del móvil usando la `IP` local del equipo `http://192.168.0.7:8081` y se abre correctamente. Si apago el servidor y le doy a refrescar se refresca y funciona. Pruebo a crear un acceso directo en el escritorio del móvil, pero si pongo el móvil en modo avion para probar la conexión offline no me abre la web, me muestra el dinosaurio.

¿alguien que haya seguido los pasos de ese tutorial o alguno parecido ha tenido el mismo problema y lo ha resuelto?

Comment: En una ocasión haciendo hacking ético a una aplicación, nos dimos cuenta que en algunas versiones de android ( no recuerdo exactamente cuales) al poner en modo avión en el dispositivo este bloquea cualquier petición de datos aunque sean en local.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verificar que tienes una función fetch en tu service worker para cachear las peticiones y devolver la pagina correspondiente cuando el usuario esté offline; y devolver una página estática,indicándole al usuario que esta offline o si tu PWA esta preparada para trabajar offline mándale las páginas requeridas desde el cache.
   Mi recomendación sería que comience por este tutorial de Google Developer [First PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/?hl=es). Considero que este tuto va antes que el de Build an offline-first, data-driven PWA.
2. Si ya tienes tu service worker funcionando y también tienes la(s) página(s) requeridas para el caso en que el usuario esta offline. Entonces es posible que tu service worker no se está actualizando. Mi recomendación para este caso es que utilices las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome y verifiques que tu PWA está cargando la última versión del service worker.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]